# View Details on Drop Down Menu HTML Code

Tags: javascript, html

Good Day!

I would like to get some help on fixing this html code. 
There will be 10 drop down list items, for example on the below code if item 1 is selected, item code details will be viewed on the text box.

however, im really new into this stuff, the text box is quite small for the details, details will be in paragraph.

Thanks

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showdv(obj, id1, id2) {
    txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = 'none';
    if (txt.match(id1)) {
      document.getElementById("box").style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById("boxx").value = txt
    }
    if (txt.match(id2)) {
      document.getElementById("box").style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById("boxx").value = txt
    }
  }
</script>

<body>
  <thead>
    <select id="opts" onchange="showdv(this,'one','two');">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="one">Item one</option>
      <option value="two">Item two</option>
    </select>
  </thead>
  <div id="box" style="display:none;">
    <input Type="textbox" id="boxx" maxlength="100">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So where is the question?

Comment: do you want to get the value of your selected option?

Comment: on how can i add paragraphs on the textbox and how it should be done :D

Comment: Then you can use a `<div>` or `<p>` to show your content!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `<div>` or `<p>` to show your content. Check below example.

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showdv(obj, id1, id2) {

    var txt = ["Item 1 description: On the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your documentOn the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your documentOn the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document",
      "Item 2 Description : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna."
    ];


    var i = obj.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = 'none';
    switch (i) {
      case 1:
        document.getElementById("box").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = txt[i - 1];
        break;
      case 2:
        document.getElementById("box").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = txt[i - 1];
        break;
    }
  }
</script>

<body>
  <thead>
    <select id="opts" onchange="showdv(this,'one','two');">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="one">Item one</option>
      <option value="two">Item two</option>
    </select>
  </thead>
  <div id="box" style="display:none;">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without sending ID's.

```js
function showdv(obj) {
    var i = obj.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = 'none';
    if (i > 0) {
        document.getElementById("box").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = document.getElementById("container"+i).innerHTML;        
    }
  }
```

```html
  <thead>
    <select id="opts" onchange="showdv(this);">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="one">Item one</option>
      <option value="two">Item two</option>
    </select>
  </thead>
  <div id="box" style="display:none;">
  </div>
<div id="container1" style="display:none;">
  Item 1 description: On the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your documentOn the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your documentOn the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document </div>

<div id="container2" style="display:none;">
  "Item 2 Description : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna." </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what I think you're asking is,

- how can I make the selected item in the drop down show details in the
  text box?

if so you'll need to make a handler on the currently selected item from the drop down and. Then populate the text inside the text box based on the value you get from the drop down (if you're doing a call to the server usually it'll be an value/id or filter criteria)

```js
//sample data that you might be pulling from a database Ajax/get
var phoneDetails = [{
  id: 0,
  name: "LG",
  price: 344.99
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "IPhone",
  price: 9000.00
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "BlackBerry",
  price: 3.99
}];

function populateDetails() {

  //get new value of the drop down
  var phoneID = document.getElementById("ddItem").value;
  var txtInputHandler = document.getElementById("txtItemDetails");
  var txtboxDetails = document.getElementById("tbItemDetails");


  //has to be async function so we  don't get undefiend.
  getPhoneDetails(phoneID, function(details) {

    //set the value of our items after the function has completed
    txtInputHandler.value = details.price;
    txtboxDetails.value = details.price;
  });
}

//get our data based on id
function getPhoneDetails(id, callback) {
  phoneDetails.forEach(function(item) {
    if (id == item.id) {
      callback(item);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<select onchange="populateDetails()" id="ddItem">
  <option disabeled selected>-- select a value --</option>
  <option value="0">LG</option>
  <option value="1">IPhone</option>
  <option value="2">BlackBerry</option>
</select>

<hr />

<input id="txtItemDetails" type="text" />
<!--there is no such thing as type="textbox" -->

<!-- what I think you wanted to do -->
<textbox id="tbItemDetails">
  </textbox>
```